# Getting the difference between 2 timestamps - javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the difference between 2 timestamps.

I have a array with saved timestamps and when i loop over them i'm trying to get the difference between then and now but it logs as `"sent:", "Hours - 0 - Minutes 0 - Seconds - 0"` and i was wondering if anyone knew why?

```js
let messages = [{
  username: "test one",
  message: "testing one",
  time: new Date()
}, {
  username: "test two",
  message: "testing two",
  time: new Date()
}];

const duration = (difference) => {
  let secondsInMiliseconds = 1000,
    minutesInMiliseconds = 60 * secondsInMiliseconds,
    hoursInMiliseconds = 60 * minutesInMiliseconds;

  let differenceInHours = difference / hoursInMiliseconds,
    differenceInMinutes = differenceInHours % 1 * 60,
    differenceInSeconds = differenceInMinutes % 1 * 60;

  return {
    "hours": Math.floor(differenceInHours),
    "minutes": Math.floor(differenceInMinutes),
    "seconds": Math.floor(differenceInSeconds)
  }
};

console.log("Wait One minute befor logging / loop");

setTimeout(() => {
  for (let i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
    let now = new Date();

    let time = duration(now - messages[i].time);
    let sent = `Hours - ${time.hours} - Minutes ${time.hours} - Seconds - ${time.hours}`;
    console.log("sent:", sent);
  }
}, 30000);
```

Sorry if my english is not good.

Comment: Pretty sure `differenceInHours % 1 * 60` should be `differenceInHours % (1 * 60)`. Same for `differenceInSeconds`.

Comment: You're setting `Hours - ${time.hours} - Minutes ${time.hours} - Seconds - ${time.hours}`, but you should be using `time.minutes` and `time.seconds` the 2nd and 3rd time. (Please don't only upvote this comment, but also vote to close due to typo.)

Comment: And arguably, it's odd to use `differenceInHours` to further calculate `differenceInMinutes` and `differenceInSeconds` because you'll likely run into floating point precision issues. It generally makes more sense to calculate from the smallest to the largest (i.e. seconds, then minutes, then hours), or just use `difference / minutesInMiliseconds` for the `differenceInMinutes` calculation, and similarly for the "seconds" calculation.

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones Oh thank you i can't believe i missed that mistake!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments mentioned, there seems to be some confusion about the modulo operator priority and then there is the bug about `time.hour` being used three times. Here's a fixed, simplified and shortened version. Since the variables declared in `duration` are only used once, and since it's a simple function, I took the liberty to inline the calculation.

```
let messages = [{
  username: "test one",
  message: "testing one",
  time: new Date()
}, {
  username: "test two",
  message: "testing two",
  time: new Date()
}];

const duration = (difference) => {
  return {
    hours: Math.floor(difference / (1000 * 60 * 60)),
    minutes: Math.floor((difference / (1000 * 60)) % 60),
    seconds: Math.floor((difference / 1000) % 60)
  }
};

console.log("Wait One minute befor logging / loop");

setTimeout(() => {
  for (let i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
    let now = new Date();
    let time = duration(now - messages[i].time);
    let sent = `Hours - ${time.hours} - Minutes ${time.minutes} - Seconds - ${time.seconds}`;
    console.log("sent:", sent);
  }
}, 30000);
```

Comment: That is really neat and shorter thank you for the help.